# Laravel, eloquent trickey relations

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

this is description of a DB ==>

```
Users [ hasOne Student]
Students (with user_id) [not all users are students, so it's "belongsTo" User] 

Groups [hasOne subject]
Subjects (with group_id) [not all groups are subjects, i use groups for other things too, so it's "belongsTo" Group]

group_user  [simple pivot table, connecting users and groups]
```

I need to get "students of a particular subject"
WITHOUT making a query per user/student since it's so many hits on db.

p.s. The relations are set fine.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to have separate model for user and student. It seems like a better idea to have just the user model with a nullable is_student column. Same with groups and subjects.

Comment: i think you are right, but i have different type of users.. seemed to be not so horrible... + a user can be student and a staff at the same time too + any other generic group

Comment: Then instead of is_student, have a user_type column, where they can be 'student', or 'worker' or whatever.

Comment: Yes but there can be multiple "types".. so i would extend it to another "side"..

Comment: How many different types are you expecting?

Comment: some users will have 1, other 5-15 types.. really changeable..

Comment: However, this helps me but again if i want to get "student" specific data through eloquent relation, it always query DB so when i list users it query students table for each user
$subject = Subject::where('id','=',$id)->first(); $students = $subject->group->users;
It would help just to add "student" data to $student

Comment: Take a look into [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading). If I understand your original question, that fixes your problem so that you won't get recursive db queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this query will help you.. I don't know the model's functions but i think you can understand it.

```
$students = Subject::with(['group.users.student'])
                    ->where('subject_name','=',$subjectName)
                    ->get();
```

Comment: since laravel docs is as it is, i was not able to understand that array in "with" at first, bit later i found the way.